# Setting up Mock properly

Tags: c#, moq

I have a helper class which inherits from an Interface and has three dependencies.

```
public class StudentHelper : IStudentHelper
{
        private readonly IUpdateStudentManager _updateStudentManager;
        private readonly ISchedulerHelper _schedulerHelper;


        public StudentHelper(
            IUpdateStudentManager updateStudentManager,
            ISchedulerHelper schedulerHelper)
        {
            _updateStudentManager = updateStudentManager;
            _schedulerHelper = schedulerHelper;
        }

        // Rest of the class not shown here for brevity.
}
```

To test this I wrote a test class like so:

```
[TestClass]
public class StudentHelperTests
{
    private Mock<StudentHelper> _studentHelperMock;

    private Mock<IUpdateStudentManager> _updateStudentManagerMock;
    private Mock<ISchedulerHelper> _schedulerHelperMock;

    [TestInitialize]
    public void Setup()
    {
        _updateStudentManagerMock = new Mock<IUpdateStudentManager>();
        _schedulerHelperMock = new Mock<ISchedulerHelper>();

        _studentHelperMock = new Mock<StudentHelper>(_updateStudentManagerMock.Object,
            _schedulerHelperMock.Object);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void Calling_GetEndDate_Returns_A_FutureDate()
    {
        _productRulesHelper.Setup(x=>x.GetEndDate(DateTime.UtcNow.ToShortDateString(),1)).Returns(DateTime.UtcNow.AddYears(1).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"));
        _productRulesHelper.VerifyAll();
    }
}
```

The method to test returns this error:

> Test method StudentHelperTests.Calling_GetEndDate_Returns_A_FutureDate
>   threw exception:
>
> System.NotSupportedException: Invalid setup on a non-virtual
>   (overridable in VB) member: x =>
>   x.GetEndDate(DateTime.UtcNow.ToShortDateString(), 1)

The GetEndDate method just takes in a date as string, adds a year and returns the resulting date as string.

I think the way StudentHelperMock is initialized is not correct!!!

Can someone please guide me on this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You haven't shown the definition of `GetEndDate`, but based on the error message it is not a `virtual` or `abstract` method. Moq works by creating dynamic sub-classes of the thing you are mocking. As such, you can think of it as this:  If you can override it in a child class, then you can mock it via Moq. Some of the other mocking frameworks do allow you to mock out non-virtual methods.

Answer (score 2):

You're not supposed to create a mock for the instance you're trying to test - you're supposed to create a mock for *its dependencies*.

The purpose of mocking is to isolate the system under test (`StudentHelper`) from its dependencies (`IUpdateStudentManager`, `ISchedulerHelper`) by replacing them with [*test doubles*](http://www.martinfowler.com/bliki/TestDouble.html) (e.g. mocks).

Here's what your test case should look like:

```
[TestMethod]
public void Calling_GetEndDate_Returns_A_FutureDate()
{
    // Arrange
    var helper = new StudentHelper(_updateStudentManagerMock.Object, _schedulerHelperMock.Object);
    var now = DateTime.UtcNow;

    // Act
    var result = x.GetEndDate(now.ToShortDateString(),1);

    // Assert
    Assert.Equal(now.AddYears(1).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"), result);
}
```

On a side note: I would also advise against the usage of global test setups. See: [Why you should not use SetUp and TearDown in NUnit](http://jamesnewkirk.typepad.com/posts/2007/09/why-you-should-.html).

Related reading:

- [The Little Mocker](https://blog.8thlight.com/uncle-bob/2014/05/14/TheLittleMocker.html) by Uncle Bob
- [When to Mock](https://blog.8thlight.com/uncle-bob/2014/05/10/WhenToMock.html) by Uncle Bob

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
[TestClass]
public class StudentHelperTests
{
    private StudentHelper _objectToTest;

    private Mock<IUpdateStudentManager> _updateStudentManagerMock;
    private Mock<ISchedulerHelper> _schedulerHelperMock;

    [TestInitialize]
    public void Setup()
    {
        _updateStudentManagerMock = new Mock<IUpdateStudentManager>();
        _schedulerHelperMock = new Mock<ISchedulerHelper>();

        _studentHelperMock = StudentHelper(_updateStudentManagerMock.Object,
            _schedulerHelperMock.Object);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void Calling_GetEndDate_Returns_A_FutureDate()
    {
        // The method name says:
       var retrievedDate = _objectToTest.GetEndDate();
       Assert()//... And you should verify than the retrieved date is "a future date" 
    }
}
```